# Coprime number pair lemma counter example sought

Tags: number-theory

Because I am yet to see a concise theoretical foundation as to why it may well be true for all natural number pairs $(n,k)$ greater than $1$, I have been seeking a counter example to disprove that:

$$\gcd\Bigl(\Bigl\lfloor\Bigl(\frac{p_n}{n}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{k+2}}\Bigr\rfloor,\lfloor n^{\frac{1}{k+2}}\rfloor\Bigr)=1 \quad\quad\forall\,n,k \in \mathbb N \,\backslash\,{\{1}\}$$

Where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number.

However this has proved to be quite infrequent and only possible at considerably large values of $n$.

Does anyone have any advice as to another approach in disproving the above lemma?

As far as proof is concerned, well, it only makes intuitive sense that it *may* be true in consideration of identities  I have previously established which can be reviewed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814343/finding-a-better-approximation-to-a-prime-number-relation)

But as you will see, there is clearly some huge gaps if indeed a concise derivation exists.

thankyou for helping in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $k$ is only $2$, then $\bigg(\dfrac{p_n}{n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{k+2}}$ will be less than $2$ until $\dfrac{p_n}{n} \ge 16$.  That doesn't happen until $n$ is well over a million, so a large value of $n$ is indeed required.

A value of $n$ that will work is $6^8 = 1679616$; then $p_n = 26941241$ and $\dfrac{p_n}{n} \approx 16.040119$.  Thus, with $k=2$,
$$
\gcd\Bigl(\Bigl\lfloor\Bigl(\frac{p_n}{n}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{k+2}}\Bigr\rfloor,\lfloor n^{\frac{1}{k+2}}\rfloor\Bigr)=\gcd(2,36)=2.
$$

Comment: did your computation there involve something to do with having expressed your value as $6^8$ out of curiosity?

Comment: For slightly smaller $n$, $\lfloor n^{\frac{1}{k+2}}\rfloor$ was $35$; I chose $6^8$ to push it up to an even value.